# Roslaunch with Arguments

Tags: ros, roslaunch, param-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to spawn a different URDF to the param server depending on the different configurations of my robot from a single launchfile. I will also launch controllers specific to that robot configuration etc. I would like to only write one controller launch script, rather than for all the different configurations of my robot.

I think this may best be achieved with an argument passed to the launch file.  Is this possible?? Something like:

```
roslaunch my_robot.launch 5_dof
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29461/roslaunch-with-arguments/) by [kmaroney](https://answers.ros.org/users/735/kmaroney/) on ROS Answers with karma: 204 on 2012-03-09

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, see the [roslaunch arg reference](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/arg).

In a nutshell, you would launch it like this:

```
roslaunch my_robot.launch dof:=5
```

Inside the launch file, add

```
<arg name="dof"/>
```

And to evaluate it,

```
$(arg dof)
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17